# Use iso3_code in country list Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, collection, model, backend

I have a dropdown list on the Magento backend extension that I'm developing.

So far, the working code for this dropdown is as follows:

`$fieldset->addField(
            'country',
            'select',
            array(
                'name'  => 'country',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Country',
                'values' => Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection()->toOptionArray(),
        ));`

It works well but doesn't deliver what I'm looking for. Yes, it adds the full list of countries on the backend, but it saves the values with the iso2_code instead of the iso3_code column on directory_country, so instead of saving *USA* it saves the value *US*

I've tried adding addAttributeToSelect and addAttributeToFilter but both throw the errors:

> Invalid method Mage_Directory_Model_Country::addAttributeToSelect(Array ( [0] => iso3_code ) )
>
> Invalid method Mage_Directory_Model_Country::addAttributeToFilter(Array ( [0] => iso3_code ) )

Could you guys please help me?

Comment: You're trying to filter a single entity (the model) instead of the selection of entities (the collection). See the getCollection() call in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a better way, but adding a helper method to your form like this should work.

```
protected function _getCountryOptions() {
    $sort = array();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->getCollection();
    foreach($collection as $country) {
        $name = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getCountryTranslation($country->getData('iso2_code'));
        if (!empty($name)) {
            $sort[$name] = $country->getData('iso3_code');
        }
    }
    Mage::helper('core/string')->ksortMultibyte($sort);
    $options = array();
    foreach ($sort as $label=>$value) {
        $options[] = array(
           'value' => $value,
           'label' => $label
        );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

And then:

```
$fieldset->addField('country', 'select', array(
    'name'     => 'country',
    'class'    => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'label'    => 'Country',
    'values'   => $this->_getCountryOptions(),
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have some questions though. Where shall I place the helper? I have the typical adminhtml block form with tab, so I have grid.php, edit.php, edit folder with tabs.php, form.php and tab folder with country.php . Then I also have the models with resources, controllers, helpers, etc.

Comment: Sorted. It works right away. Thank you very much. I've marked the answer as correct, but I can't upvote it because it requires +15 of reputation, sorry. I'll upvote once I have the reputation.

Comment: Upvoted for you